# Activate a specific Terminator profile from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors, terminator, layout

I have saved a few Terminator profiles with different colors etc.
How is it possible to activate a specific profile from the command line, or initially run terminator with a specific profile?

The main goal is to be able to activate profile "Prod" when we ssh to production, and "Stage" when we ssh to the staging-environment. So if there is such a terminator option then an alias can run the ssh command and then change the profile adequetly...

Thank you

Comment: Crossposted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328345/how-to-activate-a-specific-terminator-profile-from-the-command-line/328358

Answer (score 3):

Read `man terminator`. You will find the:

```
-p, --profile=PROFILE
          Use a different profile as the default
```

option, along with many other options.

In general, when one has a question about a command, say `terminator` for the following example, one tries:

```
man terminator
man -k terminator
info terminator
locate terminator
type -p terminator
type -a terminator
dpkg -S $( type -p terminator )
dpkg -L $( dpkg -S $( type -p terminator ) | cut -d: -f1 )
```

and then the serious investigation begins, ....

Comment: _Bonus for those that may want it!_  You can make your task bar menu icons always launch a default profile!  I copied the .desktop file for my **terminator** to /home/myuser/.local/share/applications/ and then modified the 'Exec' line to read `Exec=terminator -l "my layout"`.  In relation to this article, you could do the same, but put `Exec=terminator -p "your profile name"`  Then reload your window manager( typically by logging out, and then back in ).

Comment: Indeed the -p is helpful in case or opening a new terminal (BTW --new-tab that is supposed to open it in a new tab doesn't seem to work).


BUT, is it possible to change/activate a profile on the terminator I'm working on? (from the command-line, not from right-clicking the window)